# Python append to list issue

Tags: python, list, kivy

My issue is in regards to appending a list in Python. I am making a program with Python and kivy that gives a student a math test. The student is asked a series of random math questions, and then my goal is to give them a final grade once they are done with 50 math questions. However, I am having trouble adding their answers to a list of correct answers and incorrect answers. They may get a question for example like "2 + 2". Their answer could be 4, and I'd like to add the string 4 to an empty list called self.correct_answers. If their answer was 5, i'd like to add it to a list called self.incorrect_answers. I am using the append method to add the answer to the list, but then when the next question is asked, it deletes my prior list. So if I ask them a series of questions, the list will only contain the most recent answer. It won't contain the prior 9 answers.

Here is a piece of my code below:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Easy_Level_Addition, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def rand_numbers(self, min_num=0, max_num=10):
       """Generate a minimum/maximum number threshold for the 'easy' level.
       These numbers will fall between 0 and 10.
       """

       self.max_num = max_num
       self.min_num = min_num
       self.operation = None
       self.num_1 = None
       self.num_2 = None
       self.QUESTION = "{} {} {}"#This is how the question will be formatted

def get_random_question(self):#Number 1 and 2 will be a random integer between 1 and 10
    self.rand_numbers()
    self.num_1 = random.randint(self.min_num, self.max_num)
    self.num_2 = random.randint(self.min_num, self.max_num)
    self.operation = "+"

    self.q_s = self.QUESTION.format(self.num_1, self.operation, self.num_2)
    self.answer = str(self.num_1 + self.num_2)
    self.ids.questions_easy.text = str(self.q_s)
    #self.ids.answers.text = str(self.answer)
    self.ids.answers.text = ""
    self.ids.result_easy.text = ""

def user_answers(self):
    #Pass the prior function
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(self.answer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    self.correct_answers = []
    self.incorrect_answers = []
    self.questions_count = []
    score = 0

    if str(self.ids.answers.text) == str(self.answer):
        self.correct_answers.append(str(self.answer))
        self.questions_count.append(str(self.answer))

        self.ids.result_easy.text = "Correct!"


    elif str(self.ids.answers.text) != str(self.answer):
        self.incorrect_answers.append(str(self.answer))
        score -= int(1)
        self.ids.result_easy.text = "Wrong!"
        self.questions_count.append(str(self.answer))
```

As you can see, when I prompt the user for an answer, I want to store that answer in one of the list depending on whether or not the answer was correct. For some reason only the most recent answer is showing up in the list, and the append method is not storing a series of answers in the list.

I am also having an issue adding to the total score. As you can see in the code above I set score = 0, and then try to add +1 when the user enters a correct answer, and then -1 when the user enters an incorrect answer. However, in kivy the score doesn't add to a running total. For example, if I get 10 answers correct, the score will only show 1. It won't show 10. For some reason my program is only responding to the most recent question in terms of the lists and the total score. It is "forgetting" all of the other data.

Comment: You are resetting all those values that you want to accumulate every time you call `user_answers()`. You should move 


    self.correct_answers = []
    self.incorrect_answers = []
    self.questions_count = []
    score = 0

to the `__init__()` method.

Comment: My guess would be that you call `user_answer` method whenever an user gives answer, and each time you overwrite `self.correct_answers` etc. Those variables need to be defined once,and appending will work, but you constantly overwrite them. Can you give us a code where `user_answer` method is being called? That way, I can tell you will this resolve your issue, or if it is something else

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python/Kivy Append a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48099165/python-kivy-append-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are recreating a new list for each answer type every time you call `user_answers()`. Try removing these lines from `user_answers`:

```
self.correct_answers = []
self.incorrect_answers = []
self.questions_count = []
```

and put them in your `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Easy_Level_Addition, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.correct_answers = []
    self.incorrect_answers = []
    self.questions_count = []
```

Answer (score 1):

Scope!  Information is not stored in a function.  You could turn this into a class (and your functions into methods of that class) to keep your data alive as long as the class is still alive.

```
class MathTest:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # init any variables you need to store here 
        # then use the methods to get or change them.
    def rand_numbers(self, min_num=0, max_num=10):
        # rand_numbers code
    def get_random_question(self):
        # get_random_questions code
    def user_answers(self):
        # user_answers code
```

Then run your test through the class.

```
test = MathTest()
test.rand_numbers()
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP's code is a class. The only line missing is the class declaration. He probably meant to put the `class Classname:` at the top, but didn't copy that part.